# AlertManager maximum duration of Silence

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is there a maximum duration of silence in Alert manager? My requirement is to silence alerts coming from a specific site for a long time. When the field technicians approve the requests only then we should expire the silence and enable alerts. So, is there anyway we can setup a silences on alerts forever instead of selecting a duration?

Thanks,
Arnav

Answer (score 3):

In the [openapi silence definition](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/44af3201fe9b9492bc552583e01b31ac82fc7907/api/v2/openapi.yaml#L325) silence are defined for a begin/end time not by duration. I expect the duration in the interface is for UI only.

The format is a date-time as defined in [RFC3339](https://xml2rfc.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14). So, in theory, you should be able to set an end-time to `9999-12-31T23:59:59.999`.

The maximum duration will just depend on when you set it. In practice, it won't make a difference: if you fancy using a 100 year duration because it easier to type, it will be like forever.